# Convert data to GeoJson

Tags: python, geojson

I have a text file and want to change the format of data to GeoJson format. Firstly, I want to parse it to separated parts. I could not make a code, using python, to do that. Would you help me please to parse the data and make the GeoJson format. The initial data format is like below.

```
.A DAQT2 170314 C DH124045 /HGIRS 479.7:

.A DAMT2 170314 C DH115756 /HGIRS 425.1:

.A DBQT2 170314 C DH123840 /HGIRS 436.6:

.A DBDT2 170314 C DH120419 /HGIRS 472.3:

.A DDDT2 170314 C DH120204 /HGIRS 400.6:

.A DCNT2 170314 C DH120806 /HGIRS 412.9:

.A DBUT2 170314 C DH124633 /HGIRS 404.1:

.A DBBT2 170314 C DH121511 /HGIRS 453.4:

.A DDNT2 170314 C DH123336 /HGIRS 0.2:

.A DAXT2 170314 C DH123031 /HGIRS 438.1:
```

I generated the following code till now to separate the data (parse them) first, as follows, but it returns a line of data. I want the output to be line by line.

```
file = open('test1.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
length=lines[0].split('\n')
number_of_lines=len(length)

lines=str(lines)
data=lines.split(' ')
data=str(data)
data=data.split('\n')

file.close()
file = open('test1.txt', 'w')

file.write(str(data))
file.write('\n')
file.close()

file = open('test1.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(data))
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

The output is like:

```
['["[\':", \'1117\', \'AM\', \'CDT\', \'TUE\', \'MAR\', \'14\', 
"2017\\\\n\',", "\':\\\\n\',", "\':", \'HOURLY\', \'ACCUMULATOR\', 
\'INFORMATION\', "TABLE\\\\n\',", "\':\\\\n\',", "\':", \'NOTE:\', \'\', 
\'ERRONEOUS\', \'REPORTS\', \'MAY\', \'BE\', \'RECEIVED\', \'UNDER\', 
"CERTAIN\\\\n\',", "\':", \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
\'WEATHER\', "CONDITIONS\\\\n\',", "\':\\\\n\',", "\':", 
"**********************************************************\\\\n\',", "\':", 
\'ID\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'LOCATION\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
\'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', \'\', 
\'ACCUMULATOR\', "VALUE\\\\n\',", "\':", 
"**********************************************************\\\\n\',", 
"\':CITY", \'OF\', \'DALLAS\', \'ALERT\', "SYSTEM\\\\n\',", "\'.A", 
\'DDFT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH103231\', \'/HGIRS\', "516.8:\\\\n\',", 
"\'.A", \'DCVT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH110026\', \'/HGIRS\', 
"536.0:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDJT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH102056\', 
\'/HGIRS\', "0.0:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDUT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', 
\'DH100503\', \'/HGIRS\', "3.6:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDUT2\', \'170314\', 
\'C\', \'DH100533\', \'/HGIRS\', "3.9:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDUT2\', 
\'170314\', \'C\', \'DH100603\', \'/HGIRS\', "4.0:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", 
\'DDUT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH100703\', \'/HGIRS\', "4.2:\\\\n\',", 
"\'.A", \'DDUT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH101603\', \'/HGIRS\', 
"4.5:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDUT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH103404\', 
\'/HGIRS\', "4.7:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DDWT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', 
\'DH100740\', \'/HGIRS\', "0.0:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DCXT2\', \'170314\', 
\'C\', \'DH105825\', \'/HGIRS\', "614.1:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DCRT2\', 
\'170314\', \'C\', \'DH101815\', \'/HGIRS\', "381.1:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", 
\'DBGT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH103921\', \'/HGIRS\', "394.2:\\\\n\',", 
"\'.A", \'DBUT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH105533\', \'/HGIRS\', 
"404.1:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DBRT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', \'DH101936\', 
\'/HGIRS\', "447.6:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DBRT2\', \'170314\', \'C\', 
\'DH103306\', \'/HGIRS\', "447.6:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DBZT2\', \'170314\', 
\'C\', \'DH102317\', \'/HGIRS\', "397.1:\\\\n\',", "\'.A", \'DATT2\', 
\'170314\', \'C\', \'DH102058\', \'/HGIRS\', "448.6:\\\\n\']"]']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split(' ') "Hello world/n Hi someone/n" the output will be

```
['Hello','world/n','Hi','someone/n']
```

Then if you convert that using str the result will be

```
"['Hello','world/n','Hi','someone/n']"
```

The solution would be to do a `for` in each element of the first array.

```
data = lines.split('/n')
data[:] = [x.split(' ') for x in data]
```

This way the output for data would be:

```
[['Hello', 'world'], ['Hi','someone']]
```

Then you can write that data line by line using `for`.

For this result:

```
Hello
world
Hi
someone
```

Just:

```
for line in data:
   for word in line:
      file.write("%s/n" % word)
```

If the output you want is:

```
Hello world
Hi someone
```

Then:

```
for line in data:
   for word in line:
      file.write(word)
   file.write('/n')
```

Tip,
You can also join the data in an array:

```
>>>a = ["This","is","a","sentence"]
>>>"/n".join(a)
This
is 
a 
sentence
```

But if you try this it will give you an error:

```
>>>a = [["This","is","a","sentence"],["An","Other","sentence"]]
>>>"/n".join(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

But you can try:

```
>>>a = [["This","is","a","sentence"],["An","Other","sentence"]]
>>>a[:] = [' '.join(x) for x in a]
>>>a
['This is a sentence', 'An Other sentence']
```

Comment: In the first case just add `file.write('/n')` again in the same way.I also made some mistakes, editing the answer now

Comment: In fact you don't need `file.write('/n')` in the first case. Please accept the answer if it solved the problem :)

Comment: Sure! How should I do that then?

Comment: Just press the yes symbol in the left of the answer, below the down bote button. :)

Comment: I also added a Tip about how to use join in arrays